# How to Convert Array into String in HTML Form? [Notice: Array to string conversion?]

Tags: php, html, mysql, arrays

I am trying to take FILES in Array from HTML form, and store them in database. I have written the following code and it is giving me many error messages. It looks like that the main problem is that it is not converting Array into string.

Kindly guide me.

> ```
> Line 27 : $image_name=        $_FILES["files"]["name"];  
>
> LINE 29:  $random_name=       rand().$_FILES["files"]["name"];
> ```

**$_FILES Output**

> Array ( [files] => Array ( [name] => Array ( [0] => Bracelet_Gold.jpg
>   [1] => Necklaces_Silver.png [2] => Brooches_Gold.png ) [type] => Array
>   ( [0] => image/jpeg [1] => image/png [2] => image/png ) [tmp_name] =>
>   Array ( [0] => F:\xampp\tmp\php599C.tmp [1] =>
>   F:\xampp\tmp\php599D.tmp [2] => F:\xampp\tmp\php599E.tmp ) [error] =>
>   Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 0 [2] => 0 ) [size] => Array ( [0] => 7150 [1]
>   => 37867 [2] => 314296 ) ) )

```
<body>

<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<p>Pictures:
<input type="file" name="files[]" />
<input type="file" name="files[]" />
<input type="file" name="files[]" />
<input type="submit" value="Send" />
</p>
</form>

</body>
</html>

<?php

include 'connect.php';

if (isset($_FILES['files'])
    ||  ($_FILES["files"]["type"]   == "image/jpeg"))
    {

    foreach($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key=> $tmp_name)
        {
            //echo $tmp_name."<br>";

        echo    $image_name=        $_FILES["files"]["name"];  

            $random_name=       rand().$_FILES["files"]["name"];

            $folder="upload/products/" .$random_name;                       

            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"],
                        "upload/products/" . $random_name);




            $sql = "Insert into product_images (product_id,name,images) 
                            VALUES ($current_id,'$image_name', '$folder')";

                            if (mysql_query($sql))
                            {
                                echo 'Done';
                                }

                                else
                                {
                                    echo mysql_error();
                                    }


        }

    }

?>
```

> Notice: Array to string conversion in
>   F:\xampp\htdocs\CMS\array_upload.php on line 27 Array Notice: Array to
>   string conversion in F:\xampp\htdocs\CMS\array_upload.php on line 29
>
> Warning: move_uploaded_file() expects parameter 1 to be string, array
>   given in F:\xampp\htdocs\CMS\array_upload.php on line 34

Comment: Which lines are 27, 29 and 34?

Comment: Somewhere, something you think is a string is actually an array. This will be on the line numbers supplied by the error messages

Comment: namely, `$_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"]` seems to be claimed an array. The next step is to dig up the documentation for `$_FILES`

Comment: on 27 & 29 try $_FILES['files']['name'][$key]

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php

Comment: move_uploaded_file($tmp_name,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"] is the array of the files you are receiving
So you need to do:-

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][$key],
                        "upload/products/" . $random_name);
```

Or you are receiving current temp name in the $tmp_name so you can use:-

```
move_uploaded_file($tmp_name,
                            "upload/products/" . $random_name);
```

Comment: why not just $tmp_name

Comment: i was editing my answer to add the same while you were replying:-)

Answer (score 1):

On Lines 27 & 29 try 
`$_FILES['files']['name'][$key]`

Also replace the first parameter of move_uploaded_file with $tmp_name

```
move_uploaded_file($tmp_name,
```